# Grouped list in LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone

MS has an excellent example for this problem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

I can use this code, but it looks very strange to me.
What I don't understand:
The input is done in the order FirstName, Lastname, …
But the groups are sorted for the Lastname (the second item).
Where in the code is this information enclosed?

I found another example. It is almost the same code, but the groups are sorted for the first item in the group.

Comment: You should include the code from that article that you don't understand in your question.

Comment: I think the information I look for should be found in the
public class AlphaKeyGroup<T> : List<T>
(please look at the link I gave you)

There I would expect something like: sort for item2 or sort for “LastName”